# Serve different site maps for both www and nonwww after 301 redirect to ssl an then

Tags: .htaccess

Duplicate content problem after SSL Migration 
prefered domain: nonwww - designlab.com.mx
Ive setup this no problem, but duplicated content showing up, google selected www.designlab.com.mx as canonical.

Ive have robots.txt and robots_ssl.txt and
sitemap.xml and sitemap-ssl.xml

Not sure exactly what to do! Ive tried this

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ robots_ssl.txt [L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Welcome to SO! This seems like it might be a common problem. Have you already thoroughly searched the site for an answer?

Comment: Yes looks like a common one, Ive looked extensively and tried many variations, my experience is limited on programming, i understand the the functions but don't know coding, tried this tool that's seames to do a very good job [https://htaccess.madewithlove.be] but didnt got it right. Im half the way but my site is going down on ranking!